# LINQ query returns nulll on non-nullable field

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

on my code i've been using Linq to acces data on my Database, but there's one Table where it does'nt work. This Table has several fields :

```
ID => string, not nullable
Name => string, not nullable
Date => DateTime, not nullable
UserID => string, not nullable.
```

When I use a query to try and get those data every one of my fields returns the correct data, except one : `UserID`, it will ALWAYS return `null`, no matter what's in it.

there's my query :

```
using(ProgetEntities pg = ProgetEntities()){
   List<Alloc> ListAlloc = new List<Alloc>();
   ListAlloc = pg.Allocations.ToList();
}
```

There's my properties for Alloc :

```
public partial class Alloc
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
}
```

I Have tried using AsEnumerable in my query, but the result was the same.

Has that kind of problem happened to anyone else before ? And does anyone else have some idea of how i could try to fix this?

**EDIT**

By looking into the query i've found the problem ( i don't know why i did'nt look into it sooner), there's the query (from the debugger) :

```
pg.Alloc    {SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[NAME] AS [NAME], 
[Extent1].[DATE] AS [DATE], 
FROM [dbo].[Alloc] AS [Extent1]}    
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ClassGetMS.Models.Alloc>
```

It would seem that my query does not include the UserID field.

Comment: `List<Alloc> ListAlloc = new List<Alloc>(); ListAllocations = pg.Allocations.ToList();` Shouldn't you be assigning the `ToList` to `ListAlloc` instead of `ListAllocations`? And would this help in any way?

Comment: my bad made a typo when typing the code in, gonna fix that srry

Comment: In your database, what data type is your `UserID`? Is it an int?

Comment: The fact that in your database a field is non-nullable doesn´t mean the type of that field is non-nullable also. In particular a string is *allways* nullable. Anyway without an example of your data and how you retrieve it it´s impossible to help you.

Comment: In my DB UserID is a string, as for a string to always be nullable I agree, but it does'nt explain why it returns null no matter what's in the field.

Comment: Show your query.

Comment: _"There's my constructor for Alloc"_ That's not a constructor but the properties of your class

Comment: `public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }` can be prettified as `public DateTime? Date { get; set; }` I think. Are you running a specific linq query? Can I see it?

Comment: Are you sure the table field is mapped to class property correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty straight forward, the property was not mapped properly, so i went in the .edmx model, and added it manually, everything is working fine now.